# Regular expression for excluding overlapping matches

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in .NET that matches client/matter numbers.  A client number or a matter number consists of a series of letters or numbers, and a client/matter number is the combo of a client number and a matter number separated by `/`, `-`, or `.`.  For example `0204A/101`.

In the following string:

> Foo [1234/101] bar 456B/102 baz

I want it to match on `[1234-101]` and `456B/102`.  I've come up with this pattern for doing so:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]+[/\.\-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I can use the capture group to extract the client/matter numbers from each match.

Here's the problem:  I want to exclude dates so that the first two components or the last two components of the date are not misinterpreted as a client/matter number match.  For instance, if I have `5/3/2016` in my string -- "Foo [1234-101] bar 456B/102 baz 5/3/2016", I don't want `5/3/` to be a match.  To address this, I first tried adding `/\.\-` to the end of the final negated range:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]+[/\.\-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9/\.\-]*
```

This didn't work though because my quantifier `*` is zero-or more, so it just treats the negated range as occurring zero times and matches on `5/3`.  Next, I tried making it so the negated range either occurs one or more times or it encounters the end of the string:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]+[/\.\-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)([^a-zA-Z0-9/\.\-]+|$)
```

However, this just matched `/3/2016` which makes sense.

How can I adjust my pattern to match one instance but fail on overlapping instances?  For example, I want it to match `5/3` in `foo 5/3 bar` and `3/2016` in `foo 3/2016 bar` but not `5/3/` or `/3/2016` in `foo 5/3/2016 bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<![\/\-\.a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\/\-\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?![\/\-\.a-zA-Z0-9])
```

works perfectly as you asked, see [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC4zT4/3)

---

> Example: Foo [**`1234-101`**] bar **`456B/102`** baz 5/3/2016

Matches: **`1234-101`** and **`456B/102`**

> Example: Foo [**`1234-101`**] bar 5/22/2016

Matches: **`1234-101`**

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately it doesn't work quite right.  Try it with "Foo [1234/101] bar 5/22/2016" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't match anything at the end of the string, e.g. "Foo 1234/101".

Comment: I was talking about the one before you added the look-arounds in the last edit.  This one:  [^\/\-\.a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\/\-\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^\/\-\.a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: just took my chances :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
[^\/0-9a-zA-Z]([0-9a-zA-Z]+[\/.-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^\/0-9a-zA-Z]
```

Online demo on [regexstorm's C# regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5c%2f0-9a-zA-Z%5d(%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%2b%5b%5c%2f.-%5d%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%2b)%5b%5e%5c%2f0-9a-zA-Z%5d&i=Foo+%5b1234%2f101%5d+bar+5%2f22%2f2016+baz%0d%0afoo+5%2f3+bar%0d%0afoo+3%2f2016+bar%0d%0afoo+5%2f3%2f2016+bar%0d%0a5%2f3+bar%0d%0afoo+5%2f3%2f2016%0d%0a999&o=nm).

***Explanation***

- character classes (`[...]`) represent single characters, therefore the quantifier `{1}` is superfluous.
- You need not match the complete test string with your regex. If you want to do so, use anchors ( `^`, `$` ) as delimiters. As it stands, the regex engine will match all occurrences of your pattern when global matching is specified.
- Leading and trailing slashes cause the pattern to not match and thus keep date strings out.

***Updates***

- C# regexen do not seem to support named character classes, so reverted from the shorthand.
- Added anchors as alternative delimiters of the target pattern. Thus matches at the beginning or the end of the test string will succeed.

Comment: I tested this out with `foo 5/3` and it matched `5/3` which surprised me.  If the final `[^\/]` in your pattern is supposed to match "exactly one non-forward slash" then why does it match an input that is at the end of the string?

Comment: Okay I realized what was going on: there was a line break after `foo 5/3` so it matched with the line break (because it's not `/`).  So this pattern doesn't work when the string ends with something I want to match, e.g. if my string consists of `foo 5/3` and I want to match `5/3`.

Comment: Thanks, it still isn't quite right though.  It matches `5/22` in `5/22/2016`: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5e%7c%5b%5e%5c%2f%5d)(%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%2b%5b%5c%2f.-%5d%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%2b)(%5b%5e%5c%2f%5d%7c%24)&i=Foo+%5b1234%2f101%5d+bar+5%2f22%2f2016+baz%0d%0afoo+5%2f3+bar%0d%0afoo+3%2f2016+bar%0d%0afoo+5%2f3%2f2016+bar%0d%0a5%2f3+bar%0d%0afoo+5%2f3%2f2016%0d%0a999&o=nm

Comment: Yes, you are right. It won't work reliably without either replicating the admissible ID characters in the delimiter classes or recourse to lookaround. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

[An alternative](https://regex101.com/r/kC3xM5/2) to a look-around approach is a consuming pattern in the form `wrong|(right)`, thus:

```
\d+\/\d+\/\d+|(\b\w+[-\/\.]\w+\b)
```

you match and eat (and forget) explicitly the stuff you don't want, `\d+\/\d+\/\d+`, then in the second part after the `|` , match and remember what you do want, `(\b\w+[-\/\.]\w+\b)`